# ReactJS mapping: How do I render an html link ONLY when the url variable is not empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of products that have several links. One of the links is not populated for all of my products.

```
{ this.getSelectedProducts().map((product) => {

    const headerProductHtml = { __html: `Learn more about ${product.name}` };

    return (
        <div className="column swiper-slide" key={ `row-header-${product.id}` }>
            <div className="column__brand-background">

                <div className="column__brand-img">
                    <div className="column__brand-img-wrapper">
                        <img src={`/img/CornProductComparisonTool/logos/${product.id}_lg.png`} alt={product.name} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="column__urls">
                        <span className="column__url-learn" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={headerProductHtml}></span>
                        <a href={product.brandUrl}>View Details</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href={product.brandLabelUrl}>View Labels</a>           
                        {if (product.brandRatingsUrl){&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href={product.brandRatingsUrl}>View Ratings</a>}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="column__close" onClick={this.onCloseClick.bind(this, product.id)}></div>

            </div>
        </div>     
    );  
}) }
```

The line that I added is this:

```
{if (product.brandRatingsUrl){&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href={product.brandRatingsUrl}>View Ratings</a>}}
```

It's not working though. I'm getting an unexpected token error. What is wrong with this line?

EDIT: Changed it to this, still not working

```
<a href={product.brandUrl}>View Details</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href={product.brandLabelUrl}>View Labels</a>
{product.brandRatingsUrl ? &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href={product.brandRatingsUrl}>View Ratings</a> : null}
```

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not valid in JavaScript. You'd need to put everything inside a JSX element: `<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a>...</a></span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces inside JSX represent attribute expression ([more info](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)), that's why your `if` statement is broken. Try using ternary expression instead:

`{ product.brandRatingsUrl ? <a class="line-right" href={product.brandRatingsUrl}>View Ratings</a> : null }`

Also, as noted in comments, `&nbps;` is not valid JS. For adding vertical line before links I would use CSS (note class `.line-right` on anchor element):

```
.line-right:before {
  content: "|";
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not valid in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm still getting an unexpected token error. I updated the original post with my new code

Comment: oh just saw the edit

Answer (score 0):

Check out [If-Else in JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html).

For example, you can use a ternary statement:

```
{ product.brandRatingsUrl ? <a href={product.brandRatingsUrl}>View Ratings</a> : null }
```